# Trying to avoid polymorphic associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently in doubt whether I should use this rails feature or should I just add two columns `employee_id` and `product_id` in my Photo model.

What if both employee and product end up having same id? Will this break?

Comment: why do you want to avoid using them? Do you have any technical reason to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should definitely use polymorphic here. What if in future you will add one more model that can have a photo? You will need an additional migration to achieve it then!

It won't break on similar ids, as for polymorphic associations you will use an additional field `..._type`, like here:

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :photos do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.integer :imageable_id
      t.string  :imageable_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: hm, what's wrong with the parser?..